# Finding the middleware that interrupted a Django request

Tags: django, django-views, django-middleware

I was debugging yesterday a Django view that returned a 403 without entering the view code.  It turns out it was because I provided a `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` header without specifying the delimiter. This was "silently" rejected by some Django request parsing logic   or middleware, which returned a 403.

This makes sense, but the debugging experience wasn't great. Is there a way to make these middlewares (request parsing, auth, CSRF...) print some logs when they interrupt a request?

Comment: Just wanted to confirm, the 403 didn't have any details at all?

Comment: Better set `DEBUG=True` and try again. Hopefully, you will get some more info regarding the issue.

Comment: It didn't (I think it might have been our custom "you don't have access to this resource" HTML page)

Comment: This sounds like a situation where using pycharm & running it's debug server with breakpoints in middleware would be your best bet.